# Can Ant continue when it encounters an error?

Tags: ant

I have an Ant target that executes 2 steps in sequence:

```
<target name="release">
    <antcall target="-compile"/>
    <antcall target="-post-compile"/>
</target>
```

With the above script, it quits immediately if the "-compile" target fails. "-post-compile" does not get a chance to run. Is there a way to make sure the second step (-post-compile) is executed even if the 1st one (-compile) fails?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ant-contrib (which is very common), you could make use of the **[try-catch task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html)** and put your `post-compile` call into its `finally` element.

Also, if you are *not* using ant-contrib, then you might use the **[subant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html)** task to call your `compile` target. `subant` has a `failonerror` attribute, which you can use to individually ignore failed targets. Lots of usage examples on the [task description page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for

-keep-going (-k)

This will tell Ant to continue building all targets which do not depend on the failed target.