# How to get class files even when the build fails with ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a java project with java files more than 2500 and some of them may have compilation issue. I need to generate classfiles and route to a particular folder. Even with some of the compilation error, rest of jave turned to class files, with eclipse.

But I need to compile with build tools like ANT but it stops as build failed.
Hence no classfiles generated. Is there a way to compile and generated when project has some compilation error using ANT. The sample code is like

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="REL854" basedir="." default="compile">
    <target name="create" depends="delete">
        <mkdir dir="src"/>

    </target>
    <target name="delete">
            <delete dir ="src" />   
        <echo>exclude not working</echo>
    </target>
    <target name="copy" depends="create">
        <copydir src="C:\ClearCase_Storage\Views\Snapshot\username_view6\opensource\Selenium\REL854\src" dest="C:\Users\username\neon\ANTBuildFor854\build\src" excludes="Samples"></copydir>
        <copy todir ="C:\Users\username\neon\ANTBuildFor854\build\lib" overwrite="true"> 
        <fileset dir="C:\ClearCase_Storage\Views\Snapshot\username_view6\opensource\Selenium\REL854\lib" ></fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="compile" depends="copy"></target>
    <javac failonerror="false"  includeantruntime="false" srcdir="C:\Users\username\neon\ANTBuildFor854\build\src" destdir="C:\Users\username\neon\ANTBuildFor854\build\bin" includes="**/*.java"></javac>
</project>
```

Comment: One of the most important aspects of software is usually to be reproducable. So, to compile just the part the passes the syntax check is a really bad idea. If you don't need the part that has compile errors you should get rid of it or build separate modules/projects/whatever to decouple your stuff

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583162/can-ant-continue-when-it-encounters-an-error) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397495/how-to-handle-errors-in-apache-ant) too. (Spoiler: `--keep-going` most likely is what you're looking for.)

Comment: @mkraemerx - Thanks for the update but I have no control on the compilation error. I do not need jar /war from ant. I just want ant to compile the available java files and provide the class files. Wii it possible ? (From the available class files, I need to run some classfiles, which will fail if related compilation error and we are fine with that )

Comment: @Sami Laine - Thanks for the update. I am new to ant and build process and looking on your posts.However for me , the links help me to continue the other task if any of the task fails. but my requirement is to compile valid java files and produde at bin folder even when there are some compilation error in projetct. Say - 3000 java files and 100 will have compilation issue but the rest should create classfiles